# In Anaconda Command Prompt, unable to pip install pyflycap2

Tags: python, pip, python-3.6

I'm trying to install the pyflycap2 module in order to collect data from a camera in python. The camera came with provided software to use the camera itself, and an installer to allow the camera to interface with python 3.6. (I am currently using Python 3.6.4). Every time I try to pip install pyflycap2 so that I can run any of the python files provided by the camera manufacturer, I get a multitude of errors. Below is the output of the command prompt when I try to install the module. What's gone wrong with the install, and if possible, how can I fix it?

````
(base) C:\Users\stongduke>pip install pyflycap2
Collecting pyflycap2
 Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2c/f5/c7a24fc676b61d8c509acc83800e7f9e42764f25d770729f8afff71d0901/pyflycap2-0.3.1.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: pyflycap2
 Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pyflycap2 ... error
 Complete output from command C:\Users\stongduke\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\STONGD~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-b4ih3b42\\pyflycap2\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\STONGD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpun16b16npip-wheel- --python-tag cp36:
 running bdist_wheel
 running build
 running build_py
 creating build
 creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
 creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pyflycap2
 copying pyflycap2\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pyflycap2
 copying pyflycap2\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pyflycap2
 running build_ext
 cythoning pyflycap2\interface.pyx to pyflycap2\interface.c

 Error compiling Cython file:
 ------------------------------------------------------------
 ...
 Functions that are not implemented::

     fc2SetUserBuffers
 """

 include "includes/cy_compat.pxi"
 ^
 ------------------------------------------------------------

 pyflycap2\interface.pyx:11:0: 'includes/cy_compat.pxi' not found

 building 'pyflycap2.interface' extension
 creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6
 creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release
 creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\pyflycap2
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\STONGD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-b4ih3b42\pyflycap2\pyflycap2\includes -IC:\Users\stongduke\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\stongduke\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\cppwinrt" /Tcpyflycap2\interface.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\pyflycap2\interface.obj
 interface.c
 pyflycap2\interface.c(1): fatal error C1189: #error:  Do not use this file, it is the result of a failed Cython compilation.
 error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.32.31326\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

 ----------------------------------------
 Failed building wheel for pyflycap2
 Running setup.py clean for pyflycap2
Failed to build pyflycap2
Installing collected packages: pyflycap2
 Running setup.py install for pyflycap2 ... error
   Complete output from command C:\Users\stongduke\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\STONGD~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-b4ih3b42\\pyflycap2\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\STONGD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-7avui7kq-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
   running install
   running build
   running build_py
   creating build
   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
   creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pyflycap2
   copying pyflycap2\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pyflycap2
   copying pyflycap2\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pyflycap2
   running build_ext
   cythoning pyflycap2\interface.pyx to pyflycap2\interface.c

   Error compiling Cython file:
   ------------------------------------------------------------
   ...
   Functions that are not implemented::

       fc2SetUserBuffers
   """

   include "includes/cy_compat.pxi"
   ^
   ------------------------------------------------------------

   pyflycap2\interface.pyx:11:0: 'includes/cy_compat.pxi' not found

   building 'pyflycap2.interface' extension
   creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6
   creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release
   creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\pyflycap2
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\STONGD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-b4ih3b42\pyflycap2\pyflycap2\includes -IC:\Users\stongduke\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\stongduke\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.19041.0\\cppwinrt" /Tcpyflycap2\interface.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\pyflycap2\interface.obj    interface.c
   pyflycap2\interface.c(1): fatal error C1189: #error:  Do not use this file, it is the result of a failed Cython compilation.
   error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.32.31326\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

   ----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Users\stongduke\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\STONGD~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-b4ih3b42\\pyflycap2\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\STONGD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-7avui7kq-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\STONGD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-b4ih3b42\pyflycap2\
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 22.2.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command. ```
````

Comment: Welcome to SO! I don't know the exact problem but I'd try a couple things: 1) update pip: `pip install --upgrade pip` 2) Try it on a new virtual env in python 3.7 (3.6.4 may be too old) 3) post this error you got  on their issues page: https://github.com/matham/pyflycap2/issues and see if they reply. There have been a couple of issues like this already.

Comment: While I'd most certainly like to update python to 3.7 (in fact I had to downgrade from 3.9.7), the flycapture2 software's latest version only works on python 3.6 and below. I will, however, take your advice and post the error I got on their github page. Thank you for the help!